# yii2 image not loading in html img tag but showing in browser

Tags: php, image, server, yii2

I am using yii2 and storing the image in root folder images. I have pointed the new domain to image folder and its working fine also in browser images are getting upload also showing in a browser but when I am trying to use them in IMG tag than it is not showing.

for ref please check below url 
http://image.letspartii.com/advertisement/oJ9LFcAk2azVuGAHUrb8iyuuLqMJjUYa.png

Comment: Please give us some examples of what you've tried already. How are you specifically attempting to pass the URL to the `<img>` tag exactly? We need some code to look at to see where you're going wrong!

Comment: @Brxxn Please try to use above URL in image src and see if its working or not?

Comment: Of course it works, but we're not able to help you if you don't show us what you've tried already.

Comment: If you're viewing that image in chrome it's already in an image tag (open your console to see). This sounds like a CSS issue, are you sure theres no styling hiding the image?

Comment: add the code **YOU** are using if we use the url by creating the tag ourselves how come we will know what mistake you are making?

Answer (score 1):

**1 -** All images you want to display must be stored inside the /web folder.

**2 -** Use the relative path to call the img (starting inside de /web).

**3 -** Make sure to have the correct permission to the img folder and the file inside /web (permission and web/apache group).

Use the **Url::base()** method to get relative path:

```
<img src="<?= yii\helpers\Url::base().'/img/'.$filename; ?>"/>
```